# Validation only works for post method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to node, express wanted a help regarding validation.I am able to validate the data corresponded to post method but for put method the data is not able to get validated.What should be done for the data to get validated in put method?

Below is the user Model

```
const userSchema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 3,
        required: true,
        validate:{
            validator:function(value){
                return value.length >=3
            },
            msg:function(){
                return 'name is less than 3 characters'
            }
        }
    },
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

Below is the controller for user

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Customers = require('../model/customers')


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Customers.find()
        .then((customer) => {
            res.json(customer)
            console.log(customer)
        })
        .catch(err => res.send(err))
})

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    let customerData = new Customers({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        mobile: req.body.mobile
    })
    await customerData.save()
        .then((customer) => {
            res.json(customer)
            console.log('customer is....', customer)
        })
        .catch(err => res.send(err))
})

router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    let apiId = req.params.id
    const customerData = await Customers.findByIdAndUpdate(apiId,
        {
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            mobile: req.body.mobile
        })
    if (customerData) {
        res.json(Object.assign(customerData, req.body))
    }
    else {
        res.status(404).send('Url did not respond')
    }
})

router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    let apiId = req.params.id
    const customerData = await Customers.findByIdAndRemove(apiId)
    if (customerData) {
        res.send(customerData)
    }
    else {
        res.status(404).send('Url did not respond')
    }
})

module.exports = { customerController: router }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators)

> Mongoose also supports validation for update(), updateOne(),
>   updateMany(), and findOneAndUpdate() operations. Update validators are
>   off by default - you need to specify the runValidators option

So you have to set `runValidators: true`

```
Customers.findByIdAndUpdate(apiId,
        {
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            mobile: req.body.mobile
        }, { runValidators: true } )
```

Comment: But in this case if i only want to edit a particular field the others are showing validation error

Comment: What do you mean by others ? find and delete ? I don't think there's schema validation for find and delete, it will not create new object to be validated.

Comment: I recommend to use schema validation in web services layer instead of db layer, please find joi module, using schema validation in web service layer will give you better performance and prevent doing many stuff in case of invalid parameters, by rejecting request from web service layer not passing it to business layer and db layer.